# The UITableViewCell's expansion with long long content in iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview

1.When the content inside the cell is too long, cell expansion, Or then shrink, UITableView will scroll to the back of the cell position.

2.I want cell to roll back to where it started expansion.

my code:

```
    ((PartnershipsTableViewCell *)cell).commentSpreadButtonClickHandler = ^() {
       // just call - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
        [weakSelf.tableView beginUpdates];
        [weakCell configUI];
        [weakSelf.tableView endUpdates];

        // if here use "[weakSelf.tableView reloadData]", 
        // it can be correct, 
        // Unless on the first cell which have the expansion button.
    };
```

then update uitableview cell's height. but the result isn't what i want

```
- (void)configUI {
    if ([self.baseModel isKindOfClass: [UserWorldDynamicModel class]]) {
        self.model = (id)self.baseModel;
    }
    [self setupValue];
}

- (void)setupValue {
    // setup the property value, and update the constraints with masonry
}


// the button : read less or read more
- (void)setSpreadButton {
    NSString *text = self.model.isContentOpen ? @"read less" : @"read more";
    if (!self.spreadButton) {
        self.spreadButton = [MYSUtil createButtonWithTitle: text target: self sel: @selector(spreadButtonClick:) image: nil font: Font14 color: DarkBlueTextColor cornerRadius: 0];
        self.spreadButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
    }
    if (self.model.shouldShowSpreadButton) {
        if (!self.spreadButton.superview) {
            [self.whiteBackgroudView addSubview: self.spreadButton];
        }
        [self.spreadButton setTitle: text forState: UIControlStateNormal];
        self.spreadButton.selected = [self.model.isSpreadState intValue];
        self.spreadButton.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(self.contentLabel.frame), CGRectGetMaxY(self.contentLabel.frame), 80, 30);
        self.tempView = self.spreadButton;
    } else {
        if (self.spreadButton.superview) {
            [self.spreadButton removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
}

    // calculate the height of the label and compare it with the fixed value
    NSMutableAttributedString *string = [self createMutableAttibuteStringWithNSString: text withFont: font];
    self.contentLabel.attributedText = string;

    // here calculate maxContentLabelHeight with
    CGFloat maxContentLabelHeight = self.contentLabel.font.pointSize * (numberOfLines + 1) + 16;

    // here calculate the NSMutableAttributedString's height
    YYTextContainer *container = [YYTextContainer containerWithSize:CGSizeMake(width, MAXFLOAT)];
    YYTextLayout *textLayout = [YYTextLayout layoutWithContainer:container text: string];
    CGSize size = textLayout.textBoundingSize;
    CGFloat height = size.height;

    // then compare the NSMutableAttributedString's height with the fixed value. if true, show the spreadButton
    if (height > maxContentLabelHeight) {
        self.model.shouldShowSpreadButton = YES;
        // storage the real height and temp height, use to calculate the tableView's contentOffset, when cell from expansion state to shrinking state in block.
        self.model.contentHeight = height;
        self.model.tempContentHeight = maxContentLabelHeight;
    }

    // if height > maxContentLabelHeight and the property "isContentOpen" of the viewModel, the height value is maxContentLabelHeight, Or not, the height value is height
    if (!self.model.isContentOpen && height > maxContentLabelHeight) {
        height = maxContentLabelHeight;
    }

    // no matter cell is expansion state or shrinking state, reset label's frame.
    self.contentLabel.frame = CGRectMake(x, CGRectGetMaxY(self.headerImageView.frame) + Margin_Top, width, height);
```

Comment: Can you edit your answer to include `configUI` method?

Comment: yes, i can,but the code's very long. the method use to reset uitableviewcell's content,and calculate the cell's height

Comment: Then edit out parts that are not relevant. It is usually a good practice to isolate the problem - it can give you or anyone trying to help you a hint to the solution.

Comment: if here use "[weakSelf.tableView reloadData]",  it can be correct,  Unless on the first cell which have the expansion button.

Comment: In my question, for the contraction expansion of cell,i record the label's height which can ontract and expand, To avoid calculate the height,but i find  it can't work well.

Comment: then i use the method "reloadData" to refresh the tableView, it work well,unless on the first cell. when click the expansion button, the tableView scroll to the indexPath where i can't find it.OMG, i don't know how to fix the bug(maybe a error).

Comment: I am not getting you, do you need "read more" and "read less" functionality on cell ?

Comment: yes, i have implemented this functionality, but it can't work well

Comment: i can edit my answer include the detail method

Comment: here is example for expandable cell, hope this will help you  https://github.com/ilyapuchka/ReadMoreTextView

Comment: i have cloned the project. I also hope to solve my problem,and thank you very much for provide a solution!

Comment: i have runned the project, if the content is too long, it also can't work well. when read less,the following cell will still move up and the current cell will be occlusion.

Comment: it's just reference how to do it, you need to modify that class on your conditions

Comment: i have readed the source code, and I have edited my question just now, i paste my code of my thought.I've changed the height of cell, the click the spreadButton, but I don't know where I was wrong.

Comment: @Theorist can you help me, Or give me some suggestion

Comment: maybe, i need to debug my code by myself,then find a solution to fix the bug.god bless me!

Answer (score 0):

readMore／ readLess block

before tableView reloadData on mainQueue, record it's contentOffset, Used to calculate the position of the tableView need to scroll. like this:

```
 CGPoint point = weakSelf.tableView.contentOffset;
```

reloadData : refresh tableView On mainQueue. 
when reloadData complete, scroll tableView to the position which expanded. when tableView from expansion state to shrinking state, and the height of expansion state is greater than 70% of the Screen's height, scroll the tableView (70% is ma condition, you can change is according to your condition)

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath {
    // here is your code
    PartnershipsTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: cellIdentifierString];
    [cell config];
    ((PartnershipsTableViewCell *)cell).spreadButtonClickHandler = ^() {
        CGPoint point = weakSelf.tb.contentOffset;
        [weakSelf.tb reloadData];
        if (!baseModel.isContentOpen && baseModel.contentHeight > SCREEN_HEIGHT * 0.7) {
            point.y -= baseModel.contentHeight - baseModel.tempContentHeight;
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                weakSelf.tb.contentOffset = point;
            });
        }
    };
    return cell;
}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *) tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath {
    return 70;
}
```

in my issue, I find a another interesting problem, when use the follow method in your code. if your cell have great changes, especially the height of the cell.  when you use the method [tableView reloadData], you'd better not use the follow method.

```
 - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        return 70;
  }
```

then use the method [tableView reloadData] to refresh UI, tableView will scroll to any position, so I delete it. because, this method use to estimated height of cell, then use to estimate tableView's contentSize, if the height between estimated and actual is bigger difference, use the method [tableView reloadData], will cause the tableView scroll to anywhere.(don't ask me how to know, this is a painful process for me).

I have solved the problem, leave some notes to myself, and for every one, and hope my solution can help you too.

thanks for @pckill and @Theorist, without your suggestion, I can't solve my question so perfect, thank you very much.

@Theorist  I have reedited my code in my mind. Perhaps, the readability is better now.